# How do I find the sum of the two lowest values in a data set?

Tags: google-sheets

If the values in a set of data are 4,4,5,5,6,6 what formula would provide with the sum of the two lowest values, in this case the 4 and the 4, to equate to 8.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to answer this question. For instance, what range contains the data set? Is it vertical or horizontal? Does it always contain exactly 6 elements, or could there be more or fewer? Are all of the data points in one comma-separated string within one cell, or are they each in different cells? Will they already be sorted least to greatest as shown in your post, or is that not a given? The more careful and complete you are with what you provide, the more likely someone will be able to supply a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SMALL()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094050) function.

Try this formula:
`=SMALL($A$1:$A$6,1)+SMALL($A$1:$A$6,2)`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]